# Copy rows from table to another

Tags: sqlite

I want to copy the rows of a table `OLD` into another table `NEW`.

```
INSERT INTO NEW
SELECT date, kind, id, product, version, quantity FROM OLD;
```

The table `OLD` has a column `kind` which is `VARCHAR` and contains words like `insert`, `extract`, `delete`. In the `NEW` table this column is an `INTEGER`. Is there a way to say that if you find `delete` insert 1, if you find `extract` insert 2 etc.. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` statement to replace the string labels with integers:

```
INSERT INTO NEW
SELECT date,
       CASE WHEN kind = 'delete'  THEN 1
            WHEN kind = 'extract' THEN 2
            ELSE ...
       END,
       product,
       version,
       quantity
FROM OLD;
```

This assumes that the columns line up correctly, and all the other column types match.

Answer (score 3):

This should work for you,

```
INSERT INTO Destination SELECT * FROM Source;
```

See [SQL As Understood By SQLite: INSERT](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) for a formal definition.